# Problem with vuejs, socket and cloudflare

Tags: vue.js, cloudflare

In my VueJS i use:

```
let port = '2095';
if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') port = '2083';

const socket = io(`${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:${port}`);

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket);
```

In my server i use:

```
const app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    Redis = require('redis'),
    RedisClient = Redis.createClient(),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    axios = require('axios');
    
axios.defaults.baseURL = domain + '/api/bot/';

server.listen(2053);
```

In cloudflare use Flexible sertificate and redirect from http to https, but in console always i received:

```
GET https:/example.com:2083/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NZLTZ2x net::ERR_FAILED
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com:2083/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NZLTenH' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Where can be problem? How i can fix it? Hope for your help!

Comment: Have you worked through https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Using-Cloudflare-with-WebSockets ?

Comment: If I read it correctly, just use websockets on port 80 and 443, and proxy it within your webserver instead (e.g. proxypass with apache and the socket.io prefix)

Comment: yes, i read it, and find free websockets port and paste in my site

Comment: You also appear to be listening on port 2053 and connect to port 2083. Have you tried setting the ip for your domain manually to your production server on your machine rather than the cloudflare front that is in front of your site. This to rule out any problems with improper configuration rather than something with cloudflare.

Comment: yes, it's not work